# Why ResultSet don't return the data from MySQL

Tags: java, sql, image, swing, jlabel

I'm tying to get an image from MySQL database and show in a `JLabel`, but when I execute the query and try to get the bytes from the `ResultSet` it returns an empty array.

I tested the connection, and it is working, tested the query and its also working.

```
try {
    conn = getConnection();
    pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from imagem where serial_imagem = 123658");
    rs = pst.executeQuery()

    if (rs.next()) {
        image = rs.getBytes("img_imagem");
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well, maybe the code is throwing an exception, but you might not know since you appear to be ignoring all: `catch (Exception e) {
        }` -- don't do this, and at least print the stacktrace.

Comment: Also, you will want to divide and conquer -- break the code up into small runnable/testable units to try to identify and isolate the error. Then if still stuck, you can post [mre] code in your question, code that we can test and run and help you find your error.

Comment: are you sure that `createImage(image)` is returning an image and not `null`?  Also check what is inside `image` (print `Arrays.toString(image)`, or at least its length)

Comment: 1) I added the stacktrace, no exception printed. 2)The code was divided before, but i thought that the problem may be exactly that then i joined them all. 3) Carlos, you are right, i verified the array with the Arrays,toString, he isn't null but contains no data.

Comment: So the problem is that the ```image = rs.getBytes("img_imagem");``` isn't getting the data from the DB how i can fix that, the query is correct I'm sure, the connection goes through too, my connection has a print that state the connection.

Comment: I just verified the DB and it contains the image, so there is something happening or not happening when i try to get the image.

Comment: So, edit the question, remove all mention and code involving Swing as this is definitely not a Swing issue, but rather a database issue, show your attempts to debug the database code and your results -- clarify and simplify the code and the question.

Comment: Hover i'm sorry, but i'm not experienced at programming, so i don't know how to debug the SQL code, also tried to simplify the code, as i said, i'm inexperienced and tried to display as much information as i could, thinking that it would make it easier to find the problem. I'm sorry that this has offended you.

Comment: Please don't ascribe "offense" where it doesn't exist. I'm simply requesting that you improve the question so that it is clearer and easier to answer -- in order to *help* you get answers

Comment: That's the clearer i could think of, with my knowledge. Meanwhile i'm trying to go through a ```InputStream``` before setting it into array.

Comment: Note also that that code won't compile. The catch needs to be after the closing brace of the try block. Picky yes, but remember that your Java compiler is picky as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not close and thus leaks resources. The somewhat ugly Try-With-Resources syntax ensures closing connection, statement and result set, even on returning/exception.

One could make explicit with Optional whether the image was found in the table or not.

`Optional.of` also guarantees that the field in the database must not contain an SQL NULL value.

```
Optional<byte[]> loadImageFromDatabase(String imageM) throws SQLException {
   String sql = "select img_imagem from imagem where serial_imagem = ?";
   try (Connection conn = getConnection();
           PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
       pst.setString(1, imageM);
       try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
           if (rs.next()) {
               return Optional.of(rs.getBytes(1)); // ofNullable
           } else {
               return Optional.empty();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    try {
        Optional<byte[]> img = loadImageFromDatabase(jtextField1.getText().trim());
        img.ifPresent(image -> {
                ...
            });
    } catch (SQLException e) {
```

There is still to remark that I personally do not often use `ResultSet.getBytes`, but rather `getInputStream`. Depends on the image size and creation code.

Comment: It declares an `image` parameter of type byte[] and enters the block, only if the optional is not empty, `img.isPresent()`. So it is safe. Optional is a nice class to have.

Comment: So after the ```image -> {``` i set the img to the label?

Comment: Yes. Debug all, as I am not sure whether the error is not elsewhere, bytes wrong, or whatever.